# Check files have execute permission using CMake

Tags: permissions, cmake

I have a `CMakeLists.txt` that requires certain input files to have write permissions, otherwise the make process fails with a rather obscure "Permission denied Error 126" message. [The page here describes the usage](http://wiki.ros.org/dynamic_reconfigure/Tutorials/HowToWriteYourFirstCfgFile#dynamic_reconfigure.2BAC8-Tutorials.2BAC8-HowToWriteYourFirstCfgFile.2BAC8-catkin.Use_the_cfg_File), with the key points being:

> In order to make this cfg file usable it must be executable, so lets use the following command to make it executable
>
> `chmod a+x cfg/Tutorials.cfg`
>
> Next we need to add the following lines to our CMakeLists.txt. For Groovy and above
>
> `generate_dynamic_reconfigure_options(
>     cfg/Tutorials.cfg
>     #...
>   )`
>
> `add_dependencies(example_node ${PROJECT_NAME}_gencfg)`

How would I alter the above snippet so I could do something sensible if I forget to run `chmod` on `cfg/Tutorials.cfg` thus it is not executable?

Answer (score 0):

As described in the key points, you must make the file executable by chmod 0555 but you have to be cautious when doing this. By chmod 0555, even the owner of the file, other than root, is denied write privileges. I recommend using 0775 or something else better as it grants read and write permission.